# Bitcoin client on OpenBSD - compile error(s)

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install/compile from source BITCOIN 13.1 on OpenBSD 5.9 or 6.0. Based on the document build-openbsd.md I followed the step by step description, but fell on an error at the end of bitcoin compilation:

gmake[2]: /obj: Command not found

Makefile:9028: recipe for target 'obj/build.h' failed

gmake[2]: *** [obj/build.h] Error 127

gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/volker/Bitcoin/bitcoin13.1-src/src'

Makefile:8626: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/volker/Bitcoin/bitcoin13.1-src/src'

Makefile:558: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

I can see it complains "/obj" directory, but this directory for sure does not exist. There is a "./src/obj" directory, but this is empty...
Not sure were the error comes from. I can also see some issues with boost. I have a logfile, that I can provide on demand...

Comment: Please post the complete logfile somewhere and add a link here.

Comment: link to the compiler's logfile:

Comment: https://github.com/pebwindkraft/trx2txt/blob/master/161223_bitcoin13.1_OpenBSD59_install_issues.txt

Comment: https://github.com/pebwindkraft/trx2txt/blob/master/161225_compile.log

Comment: meanwhile found a link to: https://github.com/jasperla/openbsd-wip/tree/master/net/bitcoin, and will give it a try these days. Not sure I understand, there is no readme...

Comment: almost 6 month later, with OpenBSD 6.1, 2 Gig memory and bitcoin 14: I gave it another try, and now it runs smoothly through the process WITHOUT the wallet (--disable-wallet). Trying to analyze my logfiles for the wallet issue...